# Residually finite nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups, nilpotent-groups

It is known that every finitely generated nilpotent group is residually finite. Why finitely generated hypothesis is essential?

Answer (score 4):

It is essential in the proof, that the group is finitely generated. A finitely generated nilpotent group is supersolvable, and every supersolvable group is residually finite( a result of K.A. Hirsch). For the first part, the proof uses that the $k$-th group $G_k$ in the lower central series of the group $G$ is finitely generated for each $k$, so that each $G_k/G_{k+1}$ is finitely generated Abelian, i.e., a direct product of finitely many cyclic groups.
This is not true for nilpotent groups which are not finitely-generated.

Edit: A possible counterexample is the additive group of $\mathbb{Q}$. It is abelian, hence nilpotent, but not residually finite.

Comment: The question is not about the demonstration. It needed a counter-example?

Comment: I added a counterexample. The proof, however, gives more insight (and shows why finitely-generated is essential).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the additive group of rational numbers. It is abelian, but has no nontrivial finite quotients since it is divisible and every quotient of a divisible group is again divisible. Hence, this group is not residually finite.